# Windows Update release schedule

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

We're August 8th and I'm concerned because the last Windows Update that was applied to my computer dates from July 11th. I'm using Windows 7 Pro, SQL Server, Office 2007 and Visual Studio and I'm wondering if: a) there's a problem with the computer not updating itself or b) Microsoft just hasn't had any updates in almost a month.

So I was wondering where I could check to see when the last Windows Updates were released.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Every second and fourth tues. July 11th was a Weds. Aug 14th is the next `Patch Tuesday` I have to downvote this question for the simple fact, a Google search, would have given you this information.

Comment: @Ramhound: ok, thanks for the answer; I upvoted your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft Support - [Description of Software Update Services and Windows Server Update Services changes in content for 2012](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894199):

> This article contains a cumulative list of Windows Update content changes that have been made available to Windows Update, Microsoft Update, and Windows Server Update Services (WSUS) on or after January 10, 2012.

---

[Understanding Windows automatic updating](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Understanding-Windows-automatic-updating):

> **How often should I check for updates?**
>
> If you don't use automatic updating, you should check for updates at least once every week. Microsoft typically releases important updates on the second or fourth Tuesday of the month. However, updates could be released at any time.